# Im getting Class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory not found exception while trying to generate Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The report is working fine but when trying to export the report from Java, it throws the following exception.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 319; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 319 char 16: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory not found.
```

I tried the other solutions from the same error I faced by adding the following code

```
JRProperties.setProperty(QueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX + "plsql"
                    , "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory");
```

But the function is still giving me the same exception

The query from the jasper report works fine, but while generating the report from java I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code without any errors :

```
JRProperties.setProperty(JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX + "plsql",
                                 "com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory");
```